# clicking button with python/selenium/phantomjs

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, phantomjs

I'm trying to scrape [this](https://www.sparhandy.de/handytarife/) with a combination of **python 3.5/selenium/phantomjs**.

There is a button which loads more offers

```
<button data-behavior="result-paging" class="button button-text--centered">
    Mehr laden
</button>
```

This exact button is twice inside the HTML-Code and if all offers are listed the first button looks as follows, while the second button stays the same:

```
<button data-behavior="result-paging" class="button button-text--centered is-hidden">
   Mehr laden
</button>
```

To click the first button I tried:

```
    while True:
        try:
            time.sleep(4)
            btnElements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[@data-behavior='result-paging']")
            for btnElement in btnElements:
                btnElement.click()
                # btnElement.send_keys("\n")
                if i==11:
                    break
                else:
                    i=i+1
        except:
            break
```

and

```
    while True:
        try:
            time.sleep(4)
            elements= driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[@data-behavior='result-paging']")
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", elements[0])
            if i==11:
                break
            else:
                i=i+1
        except:
            break
```

The loop was just there for quick testing purposes since the script would run eternally otherwise. With booth approaches no new content was loaded, so clicks werent working.

Does anybody have an idea how to solve this issus (perform clicks and load other offers)?

**Edit:**

Apparently this problem is caused by phantomjs, since I could run the same script with chromedriver. Unfortunately I need to run phantomjs. Did anybody experienced this behaviour before?

Comment: You can try this xpath to click first button :- (//button[@data-behavior='result-paging'])[1]

Comment: didn't work, still doens't load anything new

Comment: Try to wait before click event.. What error you are getting ?

Comment: I am getting no error, it is like there is no click event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your code block the *Locator Strategy* which you have used as ...

```
find_elements_by_xpath("//button[@data-behavior='result-paging']")
```

... doesn't identifies the **visible** button with text as **Mehr laden** uniquely.

### Solution

To identify the visible button with text as **Mehr laden** uniquely you can use eith of the following *Locator Strategies* :

- **CSS_SELECTOR** :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  # lines of code
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[data-psa-scope=tarifflist] button.button.button-text--centered"))).click()
  ```
- **XPATH** :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  # lines of code
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@data-psa-scope='tarifflist']//button[@class='button button-text--centered']"))).click()
  ```